# iframe opens in new tab

Tags: php, javascript, forms, iframe

The problem I have just started today, without really changing the code at all. So when a form is being submitted, the value should be shown in an iframe. Everything worked fine yesterday, but today the value is shown in a new tab instad of the frame. It still works in internet explorer.

When I searched the net for answers, all they said was to add an id and name tag to the iframe, but that was already in the code. so does someone know where I could have gone wrong?

Here is part of the code

```
<form name="form_1" id="form_1" action="/fruits/result.php" method="post" target="resultaat">

<iframe name="resultaat" id="resultaat" src="/bepages/empty.php" width="660" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Edit: probably solved

It seems I found the problem, but  I think don't understand it why it went wrong. So I had **another tab** open **with the same url**. When I closed that tab, and tried again, the iframe worked fine again. I would think because it's the same id, but I'm correct that should not be a problem when you work with different tabs. So my next question, does someone know why it did go wrong here?

Comment: Which browser are you trying? I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qNBMb/ it works on Chrome 17, Firefox 9 and IE9 properly.

Comment: Just guessing. Probably you page doesn't load on 100% and browser can't define iframe. Check if you have scripts/css/images form other servers.

Comment: Could it be that the form is submitted before the iframe is parsed?

Comment: IE9, FF10,  (Chrome16, opera 11.61 and safari5 and IE9 are working fine)

Comment: yes empty.php file should be empty otherwise you have to use js with window.top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by having another tab open with the same url. When I closed 1 tab, it worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your  `<form>` tag. The  `target` attribute is set to an ID. The target is used to tell the browser which frame or window the link or form should go to. For example,
 
`<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>`  will  open a link in a new window. Whereas if you've got a frame on a page, and the frame has an ID, you can tell a link to open in that frame, by specifying its ID in the target.

Because your forms target is set to text, the browser will try and find a window or frame with that ID, or if it cant find one, open a new window, and give that window an ID of that text (in your case  `resultaat`). Try changing the target to  `self` and it should work.